# How to check if the text file is open and close the text file?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to save the text file in this path:"C:\Test\test.txt" and when the file is already opened I need to check whether the file is opened and I need to close it before writing it to the file.

Here is the code for saving the file:
   Dim myfile As String = "C:\Test\test.txt"

```
    'Check if file exists
    If System.IO.File.Exists(myfile) = True Then
        'Delete it!

        Dim fi As New FileInfo(myfile)
        fi.Delete()
    End If



    Using sfdlg As New Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog
        sfdlg.DefaultExt = "amk"
        sfdlg.Filter = "AquaMark Project|*.amk"
        If sfdlg.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then


            Dim SaveData As New gCanvasData


            IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\Test")
            Dim w As New IO.StreamWriter("C:\Test\test.txt")
            Dim i As Integer


            For i = 0 To CheckedListBox1.Items.Count - 1
                w.WriteLine(CheckedListBox1.Items.Item(i))
            Next
            w.Close()
            With SaveData
                frmDisplay.GCanvas1.UnselectCurrentAnotate()
                .gAnnotates = frmDisplay.GCanvas1.gAnnotates
                .Image = frmDisplay.GCanvas1.Image
            End With

            Using objStreamWriter As New StreamWriter(sfdlg.FileName)
                Dim x As New XmlSerializer(GetType(gCanvasData))
                x.Serialize(objStreamWriter, SaveData)
                objStreamWriter.Close()
            End Using
        End If
    End Using
```

If I am doing this way I am able to close the notepad process but I need to close the specific opened text file:

```
Dim Process() As Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad")
Process() = CType(Interaction.GetObject("C:\Test\test.txt"), Diagnostics.Process())
For Each p As Process In Process
    p.Kill()
Next
```

Comment: Now why so rude? what is wrong with his question?

Comment: updated answer with another possible solution

Answer (score 4):

I do not believe there is a property that will allow for you to check if the streamreader is open or not.

Best practice seems to be to `.close` the reader when done with it. (All in the method that it was used in.)

You could try a `try block` to handle the exception if you are still getting one.

May be able to find additional info and some sample code here. Good Luck.

[MSDN! StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx)

EDIT: You may be able to check using this. `IO.File`

```
Private Function CheckFile(ByVal filename As String) As Boolean

    Try
        System.IO.File.Open(filename, IO.FileMode.Open, IO.FileAccess.Read, IO.FileShare.None)
        FileClose(1)
        Return False
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return True
    End Try

End Function
```

Comment: It didn't work but I found the answer for this.Anyways thanks or helping me out.

Comment: @gumuruh, user676589 actually asked the question. I just edited it for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

What about :

```
If File.Exists("File1.txt") = False Then
            File.CreateText("File1.txt").Close()
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If File.Exists("File2.txt") = False Then
            File.CreateText("File2.txt").Close()
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Private Sub IsFileOpen(ByVal file As FileInfo)
    Dim stream As FileStream = Nothing
    Try
        stream = file.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None)
    Catch ex As IOException 

        If IsFileLocked(ex) Then
          'do something here, either wait a few seconds, close the file if you have  
          'a handle, make a copy of it, read it as shared (FileAccess fileAccess = FileAccess.Read, FileShare fileShare = FileShare.ReadWrite). 
          'I dont recommend terminating the process - which could cause corruption and lose data
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub

Private Shared Function IsFileLocked(exception As Exception) As Boolean
    Dim errorCode As Integer = Marshal.GetHRForException(exception) And ((1 << 16) - 1)
    Return errorCode = 32 OrElse errorCode = 33
End Function
```

Comment: use `catch ex as IOException` before `ex as Exception` to catch the exception type.

Answer (score 1):

The following function can be used to determine is a file is already open (True) or not (False).  Action can then be based on the Function result.

```
Public Function IsFileOpen(ByVal xFileName As String, ByVal xFileChannel As Integer) As Boolean
    ' ************************************************************
    ' * Function: IsFileOpen
    ' * Purpose:  To determine if a file is already open.
    ' *           Can be used to determine if a file should be closed.
    ' * Syntax:
    ' *     Dim bResult as Boolean
    ' * 
    ' *     bResult = IsFileOpen("C:\Test.txt", 1) 
    ' * 
    ' *     OR
    ' * 
    ' *     If IsFileOpen("C:\Test.txt", 1) = True Then
    ' *         Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileClose(1)
    ' *     End If
    ' * 
    ' ************************************************************
    Try
        Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileOpen(xFileChannel, xFileName, OpenMode.Input, OpenAccess.Read, OpenShare.Default)
    Catch
        ' File Already Open Error Number = 55
        If Trim(Err.Number.ToString) = "55" Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    End Try
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem with a .csv file my program attaches to an email.  I added code to clear the Attachments collection in the MailMessage object then disposing the MailMessage and Attachment objects after the mail is sent.  That appears to have fixed the problem.